# Stream file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult in a browser with a name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fileresult, filecontentresult

Is there a way to stream a file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult within the browser with a specific name?

I have noticed that you can either have a FileDialog (Open/Save) or you can stream the file in a browser window, but then it will use the ActionName when you try to save the file.

I have the following scenario:

```
byte[] contents = DocumentServiceInstance.CreateDocument(orderId, EPrintTypes.Quote);
result = File(contents, "application/pdf", String.Format("Quote{0}.pdf", orderId));
```

When I use this, I can stream the bytes, but a OPEN/SAVE file dialog is given to the user. I would like to actually stream this file in a browser window.

If I just use the FilePathResult, it shows the file in a browser window, but then when I click on "Save" button to save the file in PDF, it shows me the Action Name as the name of the file.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might be helpful for whoever else faces this problem. I finally figured out a solution. Turns out, even if we use the inline for "content-disposition" and specify a file name, the browsers still do not use the file name. Instead browsers try and interpret the file name based on the Path/URL.

You can read further on this URL:
[Securly download file inside browser with correct filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381890/securly-download-file-inside-browser-with-correct-filename)

This gave me an idea, I just created my URL route that would convert the URL and end it with the name of the file I wanted to give the file. So for e.g. my original controller call just consisted of passing the Order Id of the Order being printed. I was expecting the file name to be of the format Order{0}.pdf where {0} is the Order Id. Similarly for quotes,  I wanted Quote{0}.pdf.

In my controller, I just went ahead and added an additional parameter to accept the file name. I passed the filename as a parameter in the URL.Action method.

I then created a new route that would map that URL to the format:
http://localhost/ShoppingCart/PrintQuote/1054/Quote1054.pdf

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{controller}/{action}/{orderId}/{fileName}",
                new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "PrintQuote" }
                , new string[] { "x.x.x.Controllers" }
            );
```

This pretty much solved my issue.

Comment: A hack, but a very effective hack!  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, still needed with IE 11. Not needed with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Brillant worked for me... but one gotcha I discovered, ensure that any static file handlers don't intercept the request before it gets to managed code, that was my additional hurdle. i.e by default requests for anything *.jpg for instance don't go anywhere near the managed code, so routes are not even checked, additional [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483614/mvc-ignoring-jpg-file-extension-on-certain-route-use-controller-action)

Answer (score 102):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    byte[] contents = FetchPdfBytes();
    return File(contents, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

and for opening the PDF inside the browser you will need to set the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    byte[] contents = FetchPdfBytes();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
    return File(contents, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Hello Darin,
This opens up an OPEN/SAVE Dialog like I mentioned. I want this to open a file inside the browser.

Comment: can we have a generic value instead of "application/pdf" ? like I am not sure the type of the file. it's the user who uploaded it i the first place

Comment: We used this approach, and it causes MVC3 to send 2 Content-Disposition headers to the browser, which causes Chrome and Firefox to not display the file. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8616691/304832

Comment: @Darin: If I am calling this controller action through AJAX call, then what should be the dataType and contentType in AJAX? Because I am not getting any file open box on callin gthis action. My pdf bytes are getting genearated well.

Comment: @AnilSoman, it makes no sense to call a controller action that returns a file with AJAX. You will never get any file open box if you use AJAX.

Comment: @Darin: Yes..but my user clicks on save image icon to get the result in pdf. Hence decided to call ajax.

Comment: @AnilSoman, sorry that's impossible with AJAX. You could use a normal image button that submits the form without any AJAX call.

Comment: @Darin: ya.. seems I need to change the approach as you said. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think this should work for You:

use Darin's code on the server and run this on a client:
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ShowPdf")'; //or some other name of the action You are using

Comment: none of these answers show how to stream a file.they show how to load entire file into memory and return it. This is unnecessary and will throw OutOfMemoryException on large files.

Comment: I was able to get it working via a stream by returning File(stream, "application/pdf"). Basically I left off the third argument, the file name, and then made sure my URL had the filename in it so the browser knows what name to use if the user wants to save the file. Otherwise it will try to use whatever it can from the URL so they get the id like "1234.pdf" but if you make your url "download/1234/Whatever.pdf" then the browser will use that name instead. Except for the original version of Edge, it still can't figure out the name based on the URL but the Chromium based version can.

Comment: 14 years later - this solution worked for me. I am using .net core 6.0 and MVC. I tried it with Chrome and Edge with no issues.

Answer (score 75):

Actually, the absolutely easiest way is to do the following...

```
byte[] content = your_byte[];

FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(content, "application/octet-stream") 
{
  FileDownloadName = "your_file_name"
};

return result;
```

Comment: I would agree if the original question didn't include a byte array.

Comment: This does not work if you have a file stream like I do unless you want to read the stream into an array.

Comment: @SteveHiner The original post specifically called out byte[] as the data to be rendered.

Answer (score 9):

Previous answers are correct: adding the line...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=[filename]");
```

...will causing multiple Content-Disposition headers to be sent down to the browser. This happens b/c `FileContentResult` internally applies the header if you supply it with a file name. An alternative, and pretty simple, solution is to simply create a subclass of `FileContentResult` and override its `ExecuteResult()` method. Here's an example that instantiates an instance of the `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition` class (the same object used in the internal `FileContentResult` implementation) and passes it into the new class:

```
public class FileContentResultWithContentDisposition : FileContentResult
{
    private const string ContentDispositionHeaderName = "Content-Disposition";

    public FileContentResultWithContentDisposition(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, ContentDisposition contentDisposition)
        : base(fileContents, contentType)
    {
        // check for null or invalid ctor arguments
        ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }

    public ContentDisposition ContentDisposition { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // check for null or invalid method argument
        ContentDisposition.FileName = ContentDisposition.FileName ?? FileDownloadName;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = ContentType;
        response.AddHeader(ContentDispositionHeaderName, ContentDisposition.ToString());
        WriteFile(response);
    }
}
```

In your `Controller`, or in a base `Controller`, you can write a simple helper to instantiate a  `FileContentResultWithContentDisposition` and then call it from your action method, like so:

```
protected virtual FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, ContentDisposition contentDisposition)
{
    var result = new FileContentResultWithContentDisposition(fileContents, contentType, contentDisposition);
    return result;
}

public ActionResult Report()
{
    // get a reference to your document or file
    // in this example the report exposes properties for
    // the byte[] data and content-type of the document
    var report = ...
    return File(report.Data, report.ContentType, new ContentDisposition {
        Inline = true,
        FileName = report.FileName
    });
}
```

Now the file will be sent to the browser with the file name you choose and with a content-disposition header of "inline; filename=[filename]".

I hope that helps!

Comment: I have gone the `ContentDisposition` helper class way first, just to realize MVC was using it internally too, but with some hack for correctly handling utf-8 file name. `ContentDisposition` helper class does it wrong when it has to encode utf-8 values. For more details, see [my comment here](/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header/22221217#comment57484455_22221217).

Comment: ExecuteResult is not overridable, what to do?

Answer (score 7):

The absolute easiest way to stream a file into browser using ASP.NET MVC is this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile() {
    return File(@"c:\path\to\somefile.pdf", "application/pdf", "Your Filename.pdf");
}
```

This is easier than the method suggested by @azarc3 since you don't even need to read the bytes.

Credit goes to: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files#how_to_return_a_file_as_response

** Edit **

Apparently my 'answer' is the same as the OP's question. But I am not facing the problem he is having. Probably this was an issue with older version of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Its issue can be abstracted to 'MVC send a `content-disposition` header with `attachment` disposition when specifying a file name, how to get it send it as `inline`? Test your solution response headers, you would normally see `attachment` too.

Comment: For me this does the trick. Didn't think it was that simple until Rosdi pointed it out

Answer (score 1):

I adapted it in ASP.NET Core with REST API.

```
public class FileContentWithFileNameResult : FileContentResult
{
    public FileContentWithFileNameResult(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileName)
   : base(fileContents, contentType)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public string FileName { get; private set; }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;  
        response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={FileName}");
        response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        response.Headers.Append("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId) { 
     Product prod = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId); 
     if (prod != null) { 
         return File(prod.ImageData, prod.ImageMimeType); 
      } else { 
         return null; 
     } 
}
```