# Iframe shows ActionMethod name while loading PDF file in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, razor

i am using iframe tag in order to call ActionMethod that returns FileResult  to display PDF file. The issue is after it loads PDF document instead of showing pdf file name, it shows ActionMethod name on the top of the PDF file name in Chrome.

Razor Code:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetAgreementToReview", "Employee")" style="zoom: 0.60; -ms-zoom: 1; width: 100%;" width="99.6%" height="420" frameborder="0" id="agreementPdf"></iframe>
```

CS Code:

```
public ActionResult GetAgreementToReview()
{
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Master-Agreement.pdf");    
  return File("~/Content/Master-Agreement.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

Image: As you can see in the screenshot, it shows 'GetAgreementToReview' i.e. ActionMethod name instead of 'Master-Agreement.pdf'.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Sanjeev

Comment: You get this behavior in all the browsers ? which one you are using ?

Comment: do you have the solution for your problem

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and found a solution after exploring almost everything the web has to offer.

You must use a custom route for your action and you must send the filename from UI into the URL itself. (Other parameters won't be affected)

```
//add a route property
[Route("ControllerName/GetAgreementToReview/{fileName?}")]
public ActionResult GetAgreementToReview(string fileName, int exampleParameter)
{
     byte[] fileData = null; //whatever data you have or a file loaded from disk

     int a = exampleParameter; // should not be affected

     string resultFileName = string.format("{0}.pdf", fileName); // you can modify this to your desire

     Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + resultFileName);
     return File(fileData, "application/pdf"); //or use another mime type
}
```

And on client-side, you can use whatever system to reach the URL.

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

If you have an Iframe on HTML to display the PDF (the issue I had), it could look like this:

```
<iframe src='/ControllerName/GetAgreementToReview/my file?exampleParameter=5' />
```

And this way you have a dynamic way of manipulate the filename shown by the IFRAME that only uses the last part of an URL for its name shown on the web page (quite annoying). The downloaded filename will have its name given from server-side Content-disposition.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

please try this code :

```
return File("~/Content/Master-Agreement.pdf", "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");
```

Other Helper Link : [Stream file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult in a browser with a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name)

Comment: now it gives 'Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers..' error message. Pdf file doesn't get displayed.

Comment: Please change your code this link display method : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616824/3041974