# Display file in an Iframe MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

My problem here is I have been trying to display a pdf file in an Iframe.It works fine in IE but not working in chrome or firefox.However I am able to open them in a new tab.But as per my requirement I have to display it along with other form where data from pdf will be filled in the form.So I have used Iframes.Is there any other solution to display file along with form other than Iframes.what can i do with it? Below is the one which I tried.

```
    <iframe src="file://///GSEV/PdfsFolder/@Model.FileName"></iframe>
  <iframe src="@Url.Content("file://///GSEV/PdfsFolder/" + Model.FileName )"></iframe>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: What does it show in chrome or ff?

Comment: @SamGhatak it just shows a blank outline. along with the form to its right

Comment: well i tried out with `<iframe src="file:///C:/Work/document666.pdf"></iframe>`...works fine in all 3 browsers

Comment: @SamGhatak let me check it and let you know.thanks for responding..

Comment: @SamGhatak it doesnt seem too work for me not able to understand whats my problem when I tried it out with folder in my Application it worked previously when i used virtual path.But for this I dont understand why it isnt working.

Comment: Well I have even added plugins like local link to browsers.Even though it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure what going wrong....try creating a html page with only a iframe and hardcoded source and check

Comment: @SamGhatak I tried to open a pdf file in a folder of my application.I tried out this code and it works perfectly fine  `<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/MyPdfs/Ace.pdf")">
      </iframe>` but not able to open external file

Comment: @Rica check out my answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658690/iframe-shows-actionmethod-name-while-loading-pdf-file-in-asp-mvc/41014874#41014874 . I am not sure if you're having the same problem or something similar, but it could help you.