# How can I open a pdf file directly in my browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to view a `PDF` file directly in my browser. I know this question is already asked but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Here is my action's controller code so far:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = "~/Content/files/" + fileName;
    return File(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@{
   doc = "Mode_d'emploi.pdf";
} 

<p>@Html.ActionLink(UserResource.DocumentationLink, "GetPdf", "General", new { fileName = doc }, null)</p>
```

When I mouse hover the link here is the link:

[image]

The problem with my code is that the `pdf` file is not viewed in the browser but I get a message asking me if I wand to open or save the file.

[image]

I know it is possible and my browser support it because I already test it with another website allowing me to view `pdf` directly in my browser.

For example, here is the link when I mouse hover a link (on another website):

[image]

As you can see there is a difference in the generated link. I don't know if this is useful.

Any idea how can I view my `pdf` directly in the browser?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name

Comment: Thank you anderson.pimentel, it helped me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The reason you're getting a message asking you to open or save the file is that you're specifying a filename. If you don't specify the filename the PDF file will be opened in your browser.

So, all you need to do is to change your action to this:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = "~/Content/files/" + fileName;
    return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
}
```

Or, if you need to specify a filename you'll have to do it this way:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = "~/Content/files/" + fileName;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);        

    return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: perfect ! It's help me improve my Document management system project in our company !

Answer (score 26):

Instead of returning a `File`, try returning a `FileStreamResult`

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream("~/Content/files/" + fileName, 
                                     FileMode.Open,
                                     FileAccess.Read
                                   );
    var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    return fsResult;
}
```

Comment: @ataravati This is correct when returning stream result. if you are returning file your answer will work

Comment: @TBAG, In my answer I have explained why this is not the right answer. Because it doesn't tell you why you're getting a message asking you to open or save.

Answer (score 11):

Change your code to this :

```
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=xxxx.pdf");
       return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: This solution allows to keep the file name when the user wants to save it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file stored in database image column, you can use like this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        var data =
            db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
        if (data == null) return HttpNotFound();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=filename.pdf");
        return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(data.Fisier.ToArray()), "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although previous posts are often correct; I think most of them are not best practice!
I'd like to suggest to change action return types to `FileContentResult` and use`return new FileContentResult(fileContent, "application/pdf");`  at the end of action body.

Comment: Is FileContentResult in MVC and MVC Core?

Comment: `return File(fileContent, "application/pdf")` will return a FileContentResult -- in .net core at least

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Rotativa** package to generate PDF, Then don't put a name to file with **FileName** attribute like below example.

```
 return new PartialViewAsPdf("_JcPdfGenerator", pdfModel);
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes You Can do It Simply by redirecting . it ends extension like u need , .pdf ..**

```
protected void OpenPdfPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("jun.pdf");
        }
```

**Or another Method ,its opens like .aspx page--**

```
 protected void OpenPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("jun.pdf");
            //or you want to load from url change path to
//string path="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";   
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            }
        }
```