# Rendering a Pdf that is stored in the Database Code First Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

So iv come across this question time and time again in this forum, yet none of them cater for what i need.

1. I'm using a code first approach, c# mvc5
2. I'v managed to store a pdf to my database using a data type byte array.

I store pdf's to the database, the exact same way you would save a jpeg. I use file stream.
My question is, **how do i now display this pdf that has been stored**. I'm completely lost...help please

Comment: Select it out, save it and run it. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Im not sure exactly how to view it(select it out), from the database in my c# application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult in a browser with a name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name)

Answer (score 0):

So you already know how to make the file stream, just return a FileResult instead of a View and the client's browser will know how to display a PDF as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc).

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf", "DownloadName.pdf");
```

Comment: Okay i understand what you saying. the link that you have seems to solve my problem. just a question, for "DownloadName.pdf", i replace this with the name of the field that the pdf is stored in my database. example, i am uploading pdf version of my payslip document...so this document is stored in my database in the field payslipdocument...so i replace "DownloadName.pdf" with "model.payslipdocument"?

Comment: @Sanvir no, that is [The file name to use in the file-download dialog box that is displayed in the browser.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd492593(v=VS.118).aspx)

Comment: @Sanvir you can name it anything, "DownloadName.pdf" is just an example.

Comment: this line of code allows me to download the file return File(stream, "application/pdf", "DownloadName.pdf");

Comment: for me to view it, i used      return File(stream, "application/pdf"); and it opens up in my browser