# iText 7 Asp.Net can't open Pdf (broken)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to create a PDF using iText 7 in my Asp.Net application. Unfortunately whenever I try to open the PDF it tells me that the file is broken and can't be opened. I have no idea why because my code seems fine to me.
This is what I have:

```
public ActionResult CreateLieferschein()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
    var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    var document = new Document(pdf);
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the call to `document.Close()`

Here's the example from [their docs](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/sharp/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks), see the last line:

```
var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
var document = new Document(pdf);
document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
document.Close();
```

Comment: By the way do you know how to download this file with an Ajax request? I would open a new question if you do.

Comment: @Anokrize I think you're really close -- just grab the bytes from your newly created pdf file and pass them to the `return File(...)` call.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207274/183624