# Jasper report pdf name problem

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating pdf report in spring mvc 3 using dynamic jasper report. I am setting these headers before writting report to stream.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Report is generated and display correctly in browser but it misses its name when I try to save it, I set name here **fileName**.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

What could be the issue.

Comment: I experienced problems when the filename contains chars like "/" or "\" and maybe others. What does your file name look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `attachment`, the file will be served with the provided name properly. When `inline`, browsers seem to ignore `filename`, and usually give the servletname part of the URL as default name when saving the inline contents.

You could try mapping that URL to an appropriate filename, if that is suitable. For example, with `<servlet-mapping>`. I'm not familiar with spring mvc, so maybe there's an equivalent.

Here's a SO related question: [Securly download file inside browser with correct filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381890/851811)

You may also find this link useful: [Filename attribute for Inline Content-Disposition Meaningless?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/356076/Servlets/java/Filename-attribute-Inline-Content-Disposition)

Comment: Yes same is the case here. How can I avoid this case?

Comment: @imrantariq I've updated the answer with a possible workaround.