# Apache HTTPClient HttpGet returning nothing

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I'm doing a GET request with version 4.3.3 of Apache HttpClient, like this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.revenue.ie/en/tax/it/forms/med1.pdf");
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
client.close();
```

The response status code tells me 200, and the content length as returned by `response.getEntity().getContentLength()` is 1213954, but the `InputStream` as returned from a call to:

```
response.getEntity().getContent()
```

...is reporting 0 bytes available.

I have been successfully making GET calls like this to retrieve and parse the HTML of other URLs, but is there something different I need to do here since it's file contents that I'm interested in?

Comment: if you want to download a file why don't you use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753583/download-a-file-through-an-http-get-in-java

Comment: Just a quick guess: maybe it's cause your closing the client to early? Ie before getInputStram

Comment: @AdamGent Yes, that was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was closing the http client too early i.e. `client.close()` before I tried to retrieve the response `InputStream` with a call to `response.getEntity().getContent()`.