# How to add date and time to the file name

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

I am working on the *JasperReports* using *Spring*. I am giving the chance to customer to download the report in pdf and csv formats. But my requirement is in download prompt i need to show the file name with date and time. But I am able to show only the file name. How can I show the file name with date and time while downloading?

I am using the below code in my *jasper-views.xml*:

```
<bean id="test-pdf"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
          p:url="classpath:reports/testreport.jrxml"
          p:reportDataKey="datasource">
          <property name="headers">
         <props>
             <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                  attachment; filename=TestReport.pdf
             </prop>
         </props>
     </property>
   </bean>
```

How can i add date and time to the file name while downloading?

Answer (score 1):

before writing your stream , set the file name :

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

in the file name , you can set your date dynamically :)
and this link may be useful :
[securly-download-file-inside-browser-with-correct-filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381890/securly-download-file-inside-browser-with-correct-filename)

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you're able to show the filename because you can also specify what the filename should be when you actually generate the report. If you want to display the date and time the report is generated, and the report is generated when they press some button to download the report, you're really just displaying the current time. I don't know what value there is in that, but if it's necessary, just use some javascript to continually update the current time in their browser, maybe using a timer that fires once a minute to update the displayed time.